# Problem with link to associated object's show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to render a partial that includes a link to a 'Product' page, which belongs to a category. I am able to generate links to the product show pages if I use the array syntax of the link_to method, but there is an extra link at the bottom of my table that goes to the product index page.

I am currently using the array syntax for the link_to method to create links to the product's show page. It works but there is an extra link at the bottom of the table that points to the product's index page. If no products exist, the link is still there in it's own row. If products do exist then the link will be in an empty row at the bottom of the table.

The partial

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <%= product.product_name %>
  </td>
  <td><%= product.product_description %></td>
  <td><%= product.product_price %></td> 
  <td><%= link_to 'Product page', [@category, product] %></td>
</tr>
```

The view

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Product Description</th>
      <th>Product Price</th>
    </tr>
    <%= render @category.products %>
  </table>
```

Show action of products controller

```
  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end
```

The product's show route

```
category_product GET    /categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)                                          products#show
```

Screenshot of product routes
[output of rake routes | grep product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2m1Q7.png)

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#index'
  get 'pages/admin'
  get 'show_customer/:id', to: 'categories#show_customer', as: :show_category_to_customer

  resources :categories do
    resources :products
  end

  resources :users
end
```

I would like to have a table with only the links to the product's show pages, and not an extra link to the product index page. I have tried category_product_path(@category, product) in the partial, but I get a URLGenerationError saying the product id is nil.

I would appreciate any help on how to generate the links without getting the extra link.

Comment: Can you show your partial?

Comment: Full partial added to answer

Answer (score 0):

Your path requires product's id but you are giving uninitialized variable "product".
Tryout category_product_path(@category,@product)

Comment: I updated my answer to include the full partial. The product variable is working everywhere else in the partial and is working for the links to the product show pages also. The issue is an extra link going to the product index page instead of the show page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <%= product.product_name %>
  </td>
  <td><%= product.product_description %></td>
  <td><%= product.product_price %></td> 
  <td><%= link_to 'Product page',  category_product_path(category_id: @category.id, id: product.id)%></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: When I use this I get the following error 'ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Categories#show' 'No route matches {:action=>"show", :category_id=>1, :controller=>"products", :id=>nil}, possible unmatched constraints: [:id]'

Comment: can you run code on console on project directory `rake routes | grep product` and show the result.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the output to the question.

Comment: @user9347240 Not sure why i think there are some typo in your routes as i can see the given path should look `products#show` instead it's looking for `categories#show`

Comment: @user9347240 Would you mind to show your `routes.rb`?